# Near Death Experience and Judaism

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, death, dream

How does Judaism view Near Death experiences? do we believe they are a figment of the imagination, or do we accept them? and if we do accept them, how do we believe stories of people who claim that Yushka came to them?

Comment: Why does accepting a Near Death experience as legitimate necessitate all of the claimed ones 1) happening and 2) being reported correctly? Especially on #2, they could super-impose Avodah Zorah on any experience. In fact, that happened to one of the Chachamim that went into the Pardes, and he wasn't predisposed.

Comment: What is a Near Death experience?

Comment: @Yishai i like your rayah from pardes +1 on your comment

Comment: I heard on a tape of Rabbi Avigdor Miller that they are nonsense

Comment: `How does Judaism view Near Death experiences? do we believe they are a figment of the imagination` Your first sentence asks about Judaism, your second about Jews.

Comment: I think NDE are the figment of the imagination since people who experienced it claim to see Jesus or Krinsa. If anything, the World to Come is better, being that you can repair the world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of places where near death experience are described in the Talmud.

Here are 2, but there are more similar cases:

מסכת בבא בתרא דף י' א

> **Joseph the son of R. Joshua. He had been ill and fell in a trance.
>   [After he recovered], his father said to him: ‘What vision did you
>   have?’** He replied, ‘I saw a world upside down, the upper below and the
>   lower above.’8 He said to him: ‘You saw a well regulated world.’ [He
>   asked further]:...

ברכות כ"ח ב

> **When Rabban Johanan ben Zakkai fell ill, his disciples went in to
>   visit him.** ... **At the moment of his departure he said to
>   them: Remove the vessels so that they shall not become unclean, and
>   prepare a throne for Hezekiah the king of Judah who is coming.**

(Translation courtesy [halakhah.com](http://halakhah.com/))

To answer your second question, this have no relevance as to whether anyone else's Near Death Experience has any significance. People often see what they want to see in Real Live Experiences as well, and people make them up all the time, so one should expect that same kind of behavior with Near Death Experiences, as well.